# Securing WCF using Certificates for Transport Mode

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, wcf-security

I am using WCF service with Transport mode. I need to make this service secure using Certificates. 
I followed the steps given in the below link and got it working in my local 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF

The issues i am facing now are:-

1. In the above mentioned steps, i had the service running locally as well as my client application that calls the service, running locally. Now for my QA deployment i have the service hosted on one server and my Client application on another server.
2. I dont have visual studio commant prompt in both these servers to create the certificates using makecert.
3. My service will be in https.
4. I will be using some third party to get the certificates for my production, but now i am not able to figure out how to get this working for my QA environment.

I have tried creating a Certificate to Act as Root Certificate Authority and installed it in both the servers. In this approach also i am stuck as to how will i create my client and server certificates under this root authority.
Kindly let me know how can i get this working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. I had to create certificates using makecert in my local and then had to import them in my QA environment (will be using certificates  from a trusted third party for my production environment). My requirement was to make my service secure and not allow unauthorised clients to consume it.

My service web-config.

Changes in the binding

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings
```

Changes in behavior.

```
  <serviceCredentials>
     <clientCertificate>
         <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
      </clientCertificate>          
  </serviceCredentials>
```

My Client web-config.

Changes in binding

```
      <binding name="">
         <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
         </security> 
      </binding>
```

Add behavior

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="RootCATest"
                           x509FindType="FindByIssuerName"
                           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                           storeName="My"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Attach this behavior to the endpoint

behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior"